# Why Don't Parameters work in Azure yml template file

Tags: azure-devops, yaml, azure-pipelines

azure-pipeline.yml

```
trigger:
- master

parameters:
- name: config
  displayName: Execution Environment
  type: string
  default: QA
  values:
    - QA
    - PreProd
    - Prod
pool:
  vmImage: 'windows-latest'
```

The above works perfectly, so in Azure the Execution Environment parameter is shown when I run the pipeline.

[image]

If however I attempt to put the parameters in a template as follows:

azure-pipeline.yml

```
trigger:
- master

extends:
    template: parameters.yml
   
pool:
  vmImage: 'windows-latest'
```

parameters.xml

```
parameters:
    - name: config
      displayName: Execution Environment
      type: string
      default: QA
      values:
        - QA
        - PreProd
        - Prod
```

Then when I run the pipeline the parameter is **not** shown.

[image]

In summary I'm trying to re-use a parameters.yml in different pipelines but extends: template: does not seem to work even though per this link it should:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/security/templates?view=azure-devops#set-required-templates

Answer (score 3):

Runtime parameters are something different than templates parameters and having the second in your pipeline will not cause them to show on the UI. There is no way to template runtime parameters. You need to repeat them in each pipeline you expect to have them.